# How to initialize an array of structs to a value other than zero like 0xFF?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, initialization, linker-scripts

I have an array of structs that I need to initialize *at compile-time (no memset)* to 0xFF. This array will be written as part of the program over erased flash. By setting it to 0xFF, it will remain erased after programming, and the app can use it as persistent storage. I've found two ways to do it, one ugly and one a workaround. I'm wondering if there's another way with syntax I haven't found yet. The ugly way is to use a nested initializer setting every field of the struct. However, it's error prone and a little ugly. My workaround is to allocate the struct as an array of bytes and then use a struct-typed pointer to access the data. Linear arrays of bytes are much easier to initialize to a non-zero value.

To aid anyone else doing the same thing, I'm including the gcc attributes used and the linker script portion.

Example struct:

```c
struct BlData_t {
    uint8_t version[3];
    uint8_t reserved;
    uint8_t markers[128];
    struct AppData_t {
        uint8_t version[3];
        uint8_t reserved;
        uint32_t crc;
    } appInfo[512] __attribute__(( packed ));
} __attribute__(( packed ));
```

Initialize to 0xFF using the best way I know:

```c
// Allocate the space as an array of bytes 
// because it's a simpler syntax to 
// initialize to 0xFF.
__attribute__(( section(".bootloader_data") ))
uint8_t bootloaderDataArray[sizeof(struct BlData_t)] = {
    [0 ... sizeof(struct BlData_t) - 1] = 0xFF
};

// Use a correctly typed pointer set to the
// array of bytes for actual usage
struct BlData_t *bootloaderData = (struct BlData_t *)&bootloaderDataArray;
```

No initialization necessary because of `(NOLOAD)`:

```c
__attribute__(( section(".bootloader_data") ))
volatile const struct BLData_t bootloader_data;
```

Addition to linker script:

```
  .bootloader_data (NOLOAD):
  {
    FILL(0xFF);                  /* Doesn't matter because (NOLOAD) */
    . = ALIGN(512);              /* start on a 512B page boundary */
    __bootloader_data_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.bootloader_data))   /* .bootloader_data sections */
    KEEP (*(.bootloader_data*))  /* .bootloader_data* sections */
    . = ALIGN(512);              /* end on a 512B boundary to support
                                    runtime erasure, if possible */
    __bootloader_data_end = .;
    __bootloader_data_size = ABSOLUTE(. - __bootloader_data_start);
  } >FLASH
```

How to use the starting address, ending address and size in code:

```c
extern uint32_t __bootloader_data_start;
extern uint32_t __bootloader_data_end;
extern uint32_t __bootloader_data_size;
uint32_t _bootloader_data_start = (uint32_t)&__bootloader_data_start;
uint32_t _bootloader_data_end = (uint32_t)&__bootloader_data_end;
uint32_t _bootloader_data_size = (uint32_t)&__bootloader_data_size;
```

Update:

- It turns out that I was asking the wrong question. I didn't know about the `(NOLOAD)` linker section attribute which tells the program loader not to burn this section into flash. I accepted this answer to help others realize my mistake and possibly theirs. By not even programming the section, I don't have to worry about the initialization at all.
- I've upvoted the `union` answers since they seem to be a good solution to the question I asked.

Comment: I think the best-practice location of your mechanism depends on the use case you're trying to satisfy. Does your *code* rely on the values being set to 0xFF? Or is it more like runaway program counter detection?

Comment: You can play games with the linker and place the struct in the section filled with 0xFF, but from compiler perspective an uninitialized global struct is assumed to be zero-filled, and it might attempt to use this assumption to make certain optimization, and it can lead to unexpected issues.

Comment: Declare the array in C source code. Define the array in assembly, with suitable directives for aligning it and filling it with 0xFF bytes.

Comment: Can you define a single struct with all fields set to 0xFF, then use the GCC extension to set all array members to that value?

Comment: What about defining a `union` of your struct with an appropriately sized array, and then initializing the array member?

Comment: Declare an `extern` structure, resolve it via the linker script, and command the linker in the same script to fill the space with 0xFF.

Comment: A more rural approach is the usage of a tool to patch the resulting binary or hex file, for example "srecord".

Comment: What about instantiating it in a _separate_ `.c` file, similar to what you're doing now except no fancy linker stuff [unless you need it for alignment or need a specific load address for the ROM]. Use _one_ name (e.g. `uint8_t bootloaderdata ...`) Then, in every other `.c` file, use (e.g.) `extern struct BlData_t bootloaderdata;`

Comment: "the ugly way is to use a nested initializer setting every field of the struct." --> with macro magic could use `struct BlData_t D = {FOO(3, 0xFF), 0xFF, FOO(128, 0xFF), ...`

Comment: @JohnFilleau I'm writing the code to an erased flash chip. Erased flash has all bytes initialized to 0xFF. You can clear bits once, but you cannot set bits that have been cleared without erasing the flash again. So, I was trying to make the whole area 0xFFs so programming it would effective leave it erased. If I had written all zeros, I would never be able to use that flash memory.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I added KEEP() to the linker to prevent `--gc-sections` from optimizing out the memory. I also saw a suggestion to mark the data volatile to prevent gcc from making assumptions as well.

Comment: @thebusybee I'm thinking about that solution. I'm trying to make the code processor agnostic. Doing it your way means knowing in the linker script how much memory the code needs, and each processor may need differing amounts based on chip features. Doing it the way I did it allows the linker to figure out how big the section needs to be based on the amount of data the code declares to be in that section. The idea is that each processor can share the same linker script section without code knowledge.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for the rural approach. I was trying to make the tools work for me and keep my build simpler.

Comment: @CraigEstey I definitely need the linker alignment. On some of the processors I use, I can erase as little as 512B at a time if the memory is at the start of flash. In others, like STM32 chips, I can only erase a minimum of 32kB which effectively means I can never erase the area. So, for some chips, I can use a smaller struct and erase when necessary. On other chips, I need to make the area large enough to last the lifetime of the product.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm avoiding the "ugly" solution because it is error-prone. If someone doesn't get it exactly correct, gcc will fill in zeros. I'm going to try the union and NOLOAD solutions below this afternoon and then report back by updating the answer and accepting a solution.

Comment: @Harvey Hmm, "... because it is error-prone." --> not any more so than the alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sensible way to do this is to find the command in the linker script telling it to back off from touching that memory in the first place. Because why would you want it do be erased only to filled up with 0xFF again? That only causes unnecessary flash wear for nothing.

Something along the lines of this:

```
.bootloader_data (NOLOAD) :
{
  . = ALIGN(512);
  *(.bootloader_data *)
} >FLASH
```

Comment: I didn't even know about `(NOLOAD)`. I'm going to try that. If it works, then it's absolutely the best solution for my situation and proof that I asked the wrong question.

Comment: @Harvey With reservations for syntax. I never quite learn all these linker scripts (I've worked with ten or so different ones). But there's usually some "no load"/"no init" instruction for linkers.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `union` of your struct together with an array of the correct size, then initialize the array member.

```
union {
    struct BlData_t data;
    uint8_t bytes[sizeof(struct BlData_t)];
} data_with_ff = {
    .bytes = {
        [0 ... sizeof(struct BlData_t) - 1] = 0xff
    }
};
```

You can then access your struct as `data_with_ff.data`, defining a pointer or macro for convenience if you wish.

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6qreG7dK7)

(Readers should note that the `...` in a designated initializer is [a GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits); since the question was already using this feature and is tagged [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) I assume that is fine here.  If using a compiler that doesn't have it, I don't know another option besides `.bytes = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff ... }` with the actual correct number of `0xff`s; you'd probably want to generate it with a script.)

Comment: Was it always possible in C to initialize multiple array entries with `...`? I don't think I have seen this before.

Comment: @ssbssa No it was never possible. This is a non-standard gcc extension (and the answer ought to make that clear, nudge-nudge).

Comment: @Lundin: Figured it was fine since the question is tagged [tag:gcc] but I added a mention anyway.

Comment: @NateEldredge as you inferred, I intentionally tagged it [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) to indicate that yes, I know that I'm using GCC-only extensions.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly need to do this initialization and in pure standard C, then you can wrap your inner struct inside an anonymous union (C11), then initialize that one using macro tricks:

```
struct BlData_t {
  uint8_t version[3];
  uint8_t reserved;
  uint8_t markers[128];
    
  union {
    struct AppData_t {
      uint8_t version[3];
      uint8_t reserved;
      uint32_t crc;
    } appInfo[512];

    uint8_t raw [512];
  };
};


#define INIT_VAL 0xFF,  // note the comma
#define INIT_1 INIT_VAL

#define INIT_2   INIT_1   INIT_1
#define INIT_5   INIT_2   INIT_2  INIT_1
#define INIT_10  INIT_5   INIT_5
/* ... you get the idea */
#define INIT_512 INIT_500 INIT_10 INIT_2

const struct BlData_t bld = { .raw = {INIT_512} };
```

This method could also be applied on whole struct basis, if you for example want to initialize a struct array with all items set to the same values at compile-time.

Comment: Except the 512 in `uint8_t raw [512];` should more like 6000 and IAC, OP's code uses non-standard `packed` and this approach relies on no padding to get the size right.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Padding and initialization are two completely different topics though. Though it actually seems quite unlikely that this struct will get any padding.