# Is there a quick way to initialise a struct array with the same attributes?

Tags: c, struct

```
struct child {
    char name[32];
    int height;
};

struct child group_a[8];
```

I'd like to initialise every child in group_a with the same name and height, for example name = "XXX" and height = "100".

Is there a quick of doing it, rather than `struct child group_a[8] = {{"XXX", 100}, {"XXX", 100}, ..., {"XXX", 100}}`?

Comment: For 8 items just type it out. For a whole lot of them, you can use macro tricks such as these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71754362/584518

Comment: Use `memcpy` in a two-line loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done in standard C without deeper preprocessor magic. However there is an extension for ranges in designated initializers. It is supported by main compilers (GCC, CLANG, Intel).

```
struct child group_a[] = {
  [0 ... 7] = { .name = "XXX", .height = 100 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using compound literals like this:

```
int i = 8;
while(i--)
   group_a[i] = (struct child) { "XXX", 100 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit lame, but why not use a macro?

```
#define H {"XXX", 100}

struct child group_a[8] = {H, H, H};
```